# Dont resolve a @ManyToOne field during a query

Tags: java, sql

I have the following `DailyEntry` property:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class DailyEntry {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private LocalDate date;
  private LocalTime startTime;
  private LocalTime endTime;
  private Duration breaks;
  private String performanceRecord;
  private EntryStatus status;

  @ManyToOne
  private Project project;

  @ManyToOne
  private Employee employee;
}
```

I iterate over all `DailyEntries` of a project:

```
for (DailyEntry dailyEntry : dailyEntryRepository.findByProjectId(project.getId())) {
  // do something
}
```

This automatically generated query defined in the `DailyEntryRepository` is being used:

```
List<DailyEntry> findByProjectId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

As you see in the entity definition, `DailyEntry` has two `ManyToOne` relations to `Project` and `Employee`. That means that for each `DailyEntry` i get from `dailyEntryRepository.findByProjectId(project.getId())` two SQL queries on top of that are being used to resolve the `Employee` and `Project`. But i dont actually need them in **this** case. Is there a way to tell the system to not resolve the `Employee` and `Project` when i call `dailyEntryRepository.findByProjectId(project.getId())`? Cause i assume that would improve performance because that would reduce the amount of SQL queries by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try lazy loading Project and Employee. Lazy loading will fetch the items only when required.

```
@ManyToOne (mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```